# Duration of cache for ad-hoc statement in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, caching

I am trying to learn optimization on adhoc queries on pluralsight, the database could be found in this [link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/pluralsight-free/sql-skills/creditbackup100.zip)

When I run for the first time those queries for example:

```
select m.* from member as m where m.member_no=1
select m.* from member as m where m.member_no=3
select m.* from member as m where m.member_no=5
```

And then check the plan cache with:

```
exec  dbo.QuickCheckOnCache '%member_no%'
```

I get this result:

[image]

After that when I execute for example this query:

```
select m.* from member as m where m.member_no=34567
```

I get a new plan cache:

[image]

The expected behaviour is to update the existing plancache and not create a new one as on pluralsight video was.

So is it a question of version of SQL Server? Or what am I doing wrong?

**Note**: this is the definition of the stored procedure *QuickCheckOnCache*:

```
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[QuickCheckOnCache]
 (
    @StringToFind   NVARCHAR (4000)
  )
 AS
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 SELECT [st].[text]
  , [qs].[execution_count]
  , [qs].*
  , [p].* 
 FROM [sys].[dm_exec_query_stats] AS [qs] 
  CROSS APPLY [sys].[dm_exec_sql_text] 
      ([qs].[sql_handle]) AS [st]
  CROSS APPLY [sys].[dm_exec_query_plan] 
      ([qs].[plan_handle]) AS [p]
  WHERE [st].[text] LIKE @StringToFind
  ORDER BY 1, [qs].[execution_count] DESC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing from comments that is a problem of memory , i found [here](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/erin/sql-server-plan-cache-limits/) ,that the memory of the plan cache is calculated as below :

**75% of visible target memory from 0 to 4GB  + 10% of visible target memory from 4GB to 64GB                                                                                                   + 25% of visible target memory > 64GB**
[image: plan cache size limit]

By default, SQL Server can change its memory requirements dynamically based on available system resources ,we can set it's min value and max-value manually but for device with poor live-memory resources as mine(4gb) that would cause problems :

> Setting max server memory value too high can cause a single instance of SQL Server might have to compete for memory with other SQL Server instances hosted on the same host. However, setting this value too low could cause significant memory pressure and performance problems. Setting max server memory to the minimum value can even prevent SQL Server from starting.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server chooses the parameter type based on the literal value with auto-parameterized queries.

As you can see from the first cached plan text, a parameter type of `tinyint` was chosen for the 3 queries because of the small integer values (1,2,3). An larger `int` data type was needed for the larger value (34567). This created a different cached plan.

In summary, different parameter data types require different cached plans and the plans may be different too.

Comment: i know that , i mean the expected behaviour is to add that new plan with int data type along side the old plan with tinyint ,as you can see here sqlserver removed the old plan from cache

Comment: probably you are running it on a system with memory pressure if plans are getting dropped from cache very quickly

Comment: @A.HADDAD, I get 2 plans on my test machine.